# Uploading From App to Server in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, upload

I know that conventionally for an app to interact with the internet, it must use a web service to exchange information. However, how would one upload data(photos, text, audio recordings etc.etc.) from app to server(which holds data for all user accounts)? I know some people use an email-to-server tactic from research but even then it sounds ineffective and slow. How do apps such as Instagram upload so fast? I am trying to replicate that sort of uploading. Please guide me in the right direction.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have exchanged information with a webserver but, unfortunately I do not know what to even try with uploading hence the question

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link that shows you how Instagram is doing this ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely look into AFNetworking. Here is an example of my uploading an image to a php web service:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pageImage);

AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.SERVER.com"]];


//You can add POST parameteres here
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        author, @"author",
                        title, @"title",
                        nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/PATH/TO/WEBSERVICE.php" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {

//This is the image
    [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageData name:@"cover_image" fileName:@"temp.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];


}];



AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

//Setup Upload block to return progress of file upload
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    float progress = totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    NSLog(@"Upload Percentage: %f %%", progress*100);
}];




//Setup Completeion block to return successful or failure
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *response = [operation responseString];
    NSLog(@"response: [%@]",response);
    //Code to run after webservice returns success response code

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
    //Code to Run if Failed

}];

[operation start];
```

**Edit-** Also I use MBProgressHUD to display to the user the uploading on longer uploads.

Answer (score 4):

As you might know, upload speed is always bound to the speed of the connection type you're using. Even the best upload technique will be slow when the connection is slow (GPRS for example, or EDGE, even 3G can be slow if network coverage is not good).

To upload large sets of data faster/better one thing you could do is compressing the data you're sending using ZIP or any other file compression format you wish or even develop you own compression algorithm (you might not want to do that ;-)).

If you want to reduce the overhead of HTTP/HTTPS connections for example, you can write your very own protocol for data exchange, implement it on the client/server side and upload faster. This will be a lot of work as you have to do all the implementation work not only for the protocol itself as you need to add security etc. But even if you choose to create a protocol, as said in the beginning, it will be slow if the connection is slow.

**Update:** A presenatation by Mike Krieger (Co-Founder of Instagram) where he covers your question just crossed my way https://speakerdeck.com/u/mikeyk/p/secrets-to-lightning-fast-mobile-design?slide=1.

The reason why you think it's so fast is, that they're updating the UI before the request (the Upload in this case) even completes. This is what Mike describes as "being optimistic". If the request fails you can still notify the user, but in the meantime make him feel productive and act like the request completed successfully.

Comment: wow i see the illusion thats going on here!
looks like i should do that too :P
have the query as an asynchronous dispatch and simply just update the ui to continue onwards

thanks a lot!

Comment: That presentation is really interesting

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty open ended question but here are a few things to look at:

"Uploading fast" depends on the user's connection and server bandwidth so I won't get into that.

You can upload photos (and other files) by creating NSData objects and attaching them to a POST request. There is already a ton of sample code for uploading NSData but to convert a UIImage you will do the following:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

You can do this using the built in Cocoa classes (NSMutableURLRequest) and with 3rd party networking classes (such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ) - just scroll down to file uploads).

Comment: Thank You for this! I will do some more research on this direction and try my solution.

Answer (score 1):

When I send simple data to my webserver, I use the following approach: Use the ASIHttpRequest framework for connecting to your sever. Send the data in HTTP Post body, which is easy to do in the ASIHttpRequest framework. You will want to convert your data to either XML or JSON(use the SBJson framework for this) before sending it. I then write php scripts that parse the json or xml and then input this data into my database with custom SQL scripts. I can give you code snippets if you need them for any of these procedures...

Comment: Could you please help me with some code snippets if its not too much trouble? I could def use that!

Comment: Yeah I'm at work and don't have my macbook with me. But when I get home in a few hours I'll post it.

Comment: I'd go with the AFNetwork that as posted by mkral. That's another good framework

Comment: yup i have decided to try that!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that, with your first sentence, you've basically answered your own question.

You need something on your server to receive the files and then you write client code to match.  It could be as simple as ftp or as complex as a custom protocol depending on the security and control that you need.

Comment: Haha I guess so but the email-to-server method seems really slow. How do apps such as Instagram upload pictures directly and so fast? Are they using known methods or custom uploading protocols or as such?